# Aggregate over plus-minus 14-day window

Tags: sql, window, teradata

Suppose I have the following table:

```
|customer_id|service_date|value|
|123|2019-07-31|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-10-26|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-10-26|6.4000000000|
|123|2018-10-25|6.4000000000|
|123|2018-10-25|6.4000000000|
|123|2018-10-25|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-10-25|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-07-09|5.8000000000|
|123|2018-07-09|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-04-04|8.0000000000|
|123|2018-02-17|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-02-17|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-02-16|6.0000000000|
```

I want this:

```
|customer_id|service_date|value|
|123|2019-07-31|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-10-25|6.0000000000|
|123|2018-07-09|5.8000000000|
|123|2018-04-04|8.0000000000|
|123|2018-02-16|6.0000000000|
```

Basically for each customer in `customer_id`, I want to capture their minimum `value` over a 14-day window, and record the date in that interval on which that minimum value occurred. My database has a ton of records which are effectively duplicates since the same transaction "event" (i.e. a customer's visit to the store) are input into this database over potentially several days.

Here's what I've got:

```sql
select distinct
    a.customer_id,
    a.service_date,
    a.value,
    b.service_date as other_service_date,
    b.value as other_value,
    case
        when
            b.service_date is not null
            and b.value is not null
            and b.value < a.value
        then
            b.value
        else
            a.value
    end as master_value
from
(
    select
        customer_id,
        service_date,
        min(value) as value
    from
        my_table
    group by
        customer_id, service_date
) a
left join
(
    select
        customer_id,
        service_date,
        min(value) as value
    from
        my_table
    group by
        customer_id, service_date
) b
on
    a.customer_id = b.customer_id
    and b.service_date <= (a.service_date + 7)
    and b.service_date >= (a.service_date - 7)
    and b.service_date <> a.service_date
    and b.value <> a.value
order by
    a.customer_id,
    a.service_date desc
;
```

But I feel like I'm back to where I started. How can I more effectively create this 14-day window lookup?

Comment: How do you choose the 14 days for a 14 day window?  Why are 2018-10-26 and 2018-02-17 not in your results?

Comment: @avery_larry, I'm just using it as a rule of thumb. 2018-10-26 and 2018-02-17 are far enough apart, according to business logic for our company, to be considered the same purchasing "event".

Comment: No -- why is 2018-10-25 in your results but not 2018-10-26.  And separately, why is 2018-02-16 in your list and not 2018-02-17?

Comment: Because 10-25 and 2-16 are the earliest days on which the minimum values (6.0 each) over their respective 14-day windows occur. 10-26 and 2-17 are effectively duplicate records of those same 6.0 values, and I want the first day on which that value occurs within that window. Hoping that makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense.  We just need you to be precise so we understand.  Originally your question sounds like you want +/- 14 day window for each of the given days.

Comment: This would be fairly easy if you are allowed to use uniform 14 day windows (or any number of days).  You can just do an aggregation and group by 14 day windows (by using integer division).  But I'm guessing this won't do.  Otherwise, I believe you'll have to look at gaps-and-islands solutions.  Lots of examples by searching.  https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/e589652-7171-4310-a714-e84dd0f14090/SampleChapter5.pdf